# Getting image from API and setting it in an ImageView

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio

I'm retrieving the data from the API, and the image I'm getting it as a String.

In the API it shows something like this: `image: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYA..."`

I'm using this to set it on the ImageView:

```
byte[] outImage = r.getCover().getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
image.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

On a step by step, I saw that theImage is set as null. So at the end I see nothing.

I think the problem is when I parse it to bytes (`byte[] outImage = r.getCover().getBytes();`)

I'm getting a different data that I get from visual studio, I did a management application to upload the 'resources' and then an API to get the 'resources'. I get `[47, 57, 106, 47, 52, ...]` instead of `[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is Base64 format, you have to decode it and pass the result value to Glide. If you are not familiar with Glide, please [check out](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(Base64.decode(base64ImageString, Base64.DEFAULT))
    .asBitmap()
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you necessarily need to do this in this method?

if not I recommend using Glid.

sample code:

```
GlideApp.with(context)
    .load("image_Address")
    .into(image view);
```

more information https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

Comment: From what I'm seeing you use directly an URL meaning a .png or .jpg... I get a String, that was a byte[] and stored as varbinary in the database and then from the API is a String. I have no URL.

Comment: can you share an example of the full string your are getting?

Comment: It's too long...
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCAGqAoADASIAAhEBAxEB/"
And it continues (112528 characters)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Picasso. It's easy to implement.

```
Picasso.with(this).load(yourImageURL).fit().centerInside().into(your_imageView);
```